# jQuery animate and scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to perform two animations based on if `$(window).scrollTop()` is larger or smaller than fixed value, say 705

So the code is

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $("#scroll").html(scroll);
    if (scroll < 705){
        $("#box").animate({"height":"100px"});
    }
    if(scroll > 705){
        $("#box").animate({"height":"300px"});
    }
});
```

But the `div` with `id='box'` only does one first animation but not the second. It works if I use `.css` rather than `animate`. So what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/jCMBc/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $("#scroll").html(scroll);
    if (scroll < 705){
        $("#box").stop().animate({height: "100"}, 2000);
    }
    else {
        $("#box").stop().animate({height: "300"}, 2000);
    }
});   
});
```

Hmm. I guess you don't need jQueryUI for this. So updated fiddle.  I did add `.stop()` to stop every scroll from bubbling up. I also gave an animation time of `2000` which is equal to `2 seconds`. I also just changed your second `if` to an `else` instead.

Comment: Thank you! It works, though not as I expected. The animation will get stuck if I am constantly scrolling (with mac touchpad for example), and the animation will begin only when scrolling stops fully, since the `stop()` is always called.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the existing animation first. Also it it would be more efficient to use a flag or check for the existing height to avoid re applying the new style more than once.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $("#scroll").html(scroll);
    if(scroll > 705){
        $("#box").stop(true, false).animate({"height":"300px"});
        return;
    }

    else if (scroll < 705){
        $("#box").stop(true, false).animate({"height":"100px"});
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery animate() has default duration (default: 400).

While css() doesn't.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

To do what you need. Check out the animate()'s complete option

http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options